# FirebaseDatabaseException: Cant convert object of type java lang long to type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewholder

found this in my stack trace, what could be the problem? anyone can help with this. i am trying to retrieve object from firebase using recyclerview.

My logcat

```
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type ysy.spreadsheet.DatabaseView
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:151)
```

My structure

```
public class DatabaseView {

private Integer bodyTemp;
private Integer electroCardiogram;
private Integer perspireRate;

 public DatabaseView(){
}

public DatabaseView(Integer bodyTemp, Integer electroCardiogram,Integer  perspireRate){
this.bodyTemp= bodyTemp;
this.electroCardiogram= electroCardiogram;
this.perspireRate= perspireRate;

}
public Integer getBodyTemp() {return bodyTemp;}
public void setBodyTemp(Integer bodyTemp) {this.bodyTemp = bodyTemp;}

public Integer getElectroCardiogram() {return electroCardiogram;}
public void setElectroCardiogram(Integer electroCardiogram) {this.electroCardiogram = electroCardiogram;}

public Integer getPerspireRate() {return perspireRate;}
public void setPerspireRate(Integer perspireRate) {this.perspireRate = perspireRate;}

}
```

My View Holder

```
 public static class HealthViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView healthBodyTemp;
    public TextView healthElectroCardiogram;
    public TextView healthPerspireRate;

   public HealthViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        healthBodyTemp =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bodyTemp);
        healthElectroCardiogram=  (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.electroCardiogram);
        healthPerspireRate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.perspireRate);
```

Read from firebase

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DatabaseView, HealthViewHolder> 
mFirebaseAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //intialize RecyclerView
    mHealthRecyclerView = 
   (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.healthRecyclerView);
    mlinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mlinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mHealthRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlinearLayoutManager);

    //Database Initilization
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DatabaseView, 
    HealthViewHolder>(
            DatabaseView.class,
            R.layout.database_view,
            HealthViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(HEALTH))
```

Comment: to Type... what? Please show all the logcat

Comment: @cricket_007 i uploaded the top part of the logcat

Comment: @michysy22 show us your database structure which you are trying to display in RecyclerView...

Comment: @michysy22 show json data to understood where is problem

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay i can't upload the screenshot here but it has a child (health) and children (bodyTemp:10, electroCardiogram =80, perspireRate= 30). Thats it.

Comment: @michysy22 try to replace `Intenger` with `int` in your DatabaseView class..

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay i just did but the stack trace still shows the same line

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes edited, thanks

Comment: Can you also show us your database? It looks like you're trying to read DatabaseView in a node that contains a long value. Also, what's the value of the constant `HEALTH`?